# How to develop on multiple computers with Libgdx and Intellij Idea

Tags: java, git, svn, intellij-idea, libgdx

I have a laptop and a desktop computer. At the moment I can only code on the desktop where i have created and developed the project for now. When I load up the project, which  sync with Copy.com by the way, it doesnt work because all the library-paths isn't the same on the laptop and the desktop.

Is there anything I can do? I've heard of Git, SVN and all this, but I dont know how to set them up, and I dont know how to make the library-paths relative instead of absolute.

Thanks

Comment: Use a build tool like Maven or Gradle.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to set it up :)

Comment: Have you attempted to try to find out how to use a build tool?

Comment: I know that libgdx uses Gradle, but I've been using the GUI in Intellij to add Libraries, am i supposed to add them in the gradle file? :)

Comment: I asked if you have attempted to use a build tool because if you have, then you must have ran into more specific problems that you could ask about here instead of this unspecific question you have now that is really unanswerable. It seems like your first real question that you would like answered is are Intellij project files good enough to use as a portable build script, and I would say no. Think of your IDE's project files as a build script, but a crappy one. Often it's not that independent of your file system layout nor is it in a format that people with other IDEs can use.

Comment: Also, Git and Subversion are examples of version control software, which is software that lets you store revisions of your files, to use as backups, history, that sort of thing. These are different than build tools like Maven and Gradle.

Comment: Thanks for answering some of my problems :) I will now look into gradle and how to use it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a build tool like Maven or Gradle to manage the libraries. (You can use Maven, even if libgdx uses Gradle, it doesn't matter). These tools help in downloading the required libraries and creating a uniform project structure. Checkout some Maven/Gradle tutorial online.

Use source control tools like Git for saving your project. Use a central storage place like Github, bitbucket or gitlab, so that you can sync your project from any place you want. You can find an excellent git tutorial over [here](http://git-scm.com/documentation) and [here](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1)

Make yourself comfortable with these tools. It is independent of any IDE.